# How can I add a shadow to text in an image?

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

How can I add a shadow to text like in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk4kk.png

[image]

I am generating the text in an image with the following code. But I don't know what to do to add the shadow:

```
gm(filename)
    .font("Arial")
    .fontSize(72)
    .drawText(0, 0, text, 'Center')
    .write("./result.png", clb);
```

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to do text shadows it to draw the same text twice. First instance to be shadow, and then the actual text on top.

Example

```
convert wizard: -font Arial -pointsize 72 -gravity center \
        -fill black -draw 'text 1 1 "Hello_World"' \
        -fill pink  -draw 'text 0 0 "Hello_World"' \
        ./result.png
```

[image: add a shadow to text]

You can add blur, or other effects, of the shadow interdependently of the image. See [examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/fonts/#soft_outline).

I don't know much about javascript `gm`, but I would imagine it could look something like...

```js
gm(filename)
    .font("Arial")
    .fontSize(72)
    .fill(shadowColor)
    .drawText(1, 1, text, 'Center')
    .fill(textColor)
    .drawText(0, 0, text, 'Center')
    .write("./result.png", clb);
```